# How can I match all groups in string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match `dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0008,0020)'), Q$String_$1)`:

```
header.containsKey('(0008,0020)')?(dateString = dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0008,0020)'), Q$String_$1)[0]):header.containsKey('(0008,0022)')?(dateString = dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0008,0022)'), Q$String_$1)[0]):header.containsKey('(0008,0021)')?(dateString = dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0008,0021)'), Q$String_$1)[0]):header.containsKey('(0008,0023)') && (dateString = dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0008,0023)'), Q$String_$1)[0]);
```

I managed to make it work with this regex

```
dynamicCast\(header.get.*, Q\$(String_|int_)\$1\)
```

The problem is, it matches the whole block. What is the proper regex magic spell to get the four matches I want?

I'm currently rewriting auto-generated JavaScript using a regex using Ruby. I'm then replacing each match with

```
header.get_0('(0008,0020)')
```

One a problem is I have to match some different flavors, inside the method `get_0` there are many different possibilities. I might need to match every single possibility, and then, why use regex?

```
dynamicCast(header.get_0('(0028,' + element + ')'), Q$String_$1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
dynamicCast\(header\.get_0\('\([^)]+\)'\), Q\$(?:String_|int_)\$1\)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/5)

Comment: Got me one step closer but it definitely helped... see my edit.

Comment: @code-gijoe welcome.. and what do you mean by `I might need to match every single possibility` ? what could be some possible examples?

Comment: well, as defined by the language, the method call to "get_0" receives and input that is a string that can be expressed in many forms, but, it's always in the form of get_0('ANYTHING IN HERE'). But if I use get_0\(\.*'\), it matches up to the end...

Comment: You could tighten by adding a positive lookbehind `(?<=dateString\s=\s)` before and a positive lookahead `(?=\[0\])` after.